# Router DHCP not working with switch

Tags: router, dhcp, switch

I just hooked up a [Dell PowerConnect 2824](http://www1.ca.dell.com/ca/en/business/networking/switch-powerconnect-2824/pd.aspx?refid=switch-powerconnect-2824&s=bsd&cs=cabsdt1) in 'unmanaged mode' into our network and our router, a DLink DI-524, will no longer apply IP addresses via the DHCP to anything connected to the switch. In fact nothing connected to the switch even shows in the routers tables.

I am wondering if the router simply doesn't have the functionality to be able to work through the switch or if there is something wrong with the switch.

If you feel it is the router I was looking at something like the [Cisco RV042](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9925/index.html) as I need remote VPN control although I would prefer a 10/100/1000 setup. so if anyone has any comments about that router or if there is something of better value please let me know.

My setup is as follows:
Modem -> Router -> Switch ->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably switch is not relaying dhcp requests to the router. To verify it, if you have physical access to these devices, you could plug a laptop instead of the switch , and see what happens.

If the laptop take an IP, it's switch's problem. In that case, you should just fix it to relay the requests.

Comment: Once I was able to properly setup the switch in the 'managed' mode it was clear that it was simply not passing the information to the router.

Answer (score 2):

The PowerConnect 2824 appears to have a DHCP server as well.  Is it disabled?  As an option and troubleshooting, can you disable DHCP on the router and use the DHCP server on the PowerConnect 2824 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

My gut says that you've got a physical layer problem (speed or duplex mismatch, or cabling problem) between the D-Link router and the PowerConnect switch. I suspect you're using the wifi functionality to manage the router and haven't actually verified, using a PC with a wired Ethernet NIC and a statically-assigned IP address, that there is good Ethernet communication between the D-Link and the PowerConnect. I'd do that now and see how it looks.

Comment: In attempting to switch to managed mode I found that I needed to connect via the serial port to enable the web functionality. Which I am now unable to figure out.. http://serverfault.com/questions/161288/using-putty-for-serial-connection